# Defining minimum cache size for input data with specific frequency and frame rate

Tags: caching, image-processing, video-streaming, compiler-optimization

**Task:** My requirement is to find the minimum cache size to process the frame and details are as below:

**Please help with calculations:**

Consider a camera capturing a 2K resolution video at 30 FPS format is NV12.

> Consider the requirement of a pre-processing step on DSP which need to
>   be applied on the captured video by directly streaming the data in to
>   the cache of the DSP.

DSP @800MHZ @10x step Cycles, 64 bytes of data, **Q.** what is the minimum data size needed to stream a cache of 30FPS?

> If the DSP is running at 800 MHZ and the processing step needs 10
>   Cycles of DSP for processing 64 bytes of Data, what is the minimum
>   data Size that need to be streamed in the cache so that 30FPS is met.

**Q.** Can any one also comment if the DSP running at 800 MHz will suffice for doing a pre-processing of 4K video at 30FPS?

**Q.** Can any one please help me understanding the minimum cache size required in such senarios. I googled about cache but no where found the size relations with the frequency.